# Coloring by variable for phyloseq boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, phyloseq

I have a boxplot (see below) that I'd like to color by the variables according to a specified palette. I'm not sure how to color them as the code is based on the Phyloseq package. I tried having `aes()` in `plot_richness`, but it seems to only work for `geom_boxplot()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(phyloseq)

palette <- c("#B0F2E7", "#166AD0", "#F89EE9", "#DA0000", "#C6C3D3", "#23202C")

plot_richness(physeq_shime, x='System', measures='Shannon') + theme_bw() + 
  xlab('SHIME') + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(2.0,3.2)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill='System'))
```

How can I fill the boxplots in the order of the custom palette?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Figure 1. Boxplots in Phyloseq]

Comment: How does the data look like, provide example? Maybe use `ggplot(...) + geom_boxplot()` without phyloseq, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52507872/680068

Comment: I didn't post the data as the dataset is based on the phyloseq object. It wouldn't be possible for me to have the alpha diversity values outside of phyloseq unless i used a different program.

Comment: What if you feed 'palette' to the 'color' argument of `plot_richness`? `plot_richness(physeq_shime, x='System', measures='Shannon', color = palette)`

Comment: Doesn't work as it says "Error: No expression to parse". I've tried playing around with the `color=` on `plot_richness`, but it hasn't worked yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
library(ggplot2)
library(phyloseq)

palette <- c("#B0F2E7", "#166AD0", "#F89EE9", "#DA0000", "#C6C3D3", "#23202C")

plot_richness(physeq_shime, x='System', measures='Shannon') + theme_bw() + 
  xlab('SHIME') + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(2.0,3.2)) + 
  geom_boxplot(lwd=0.9, alpha=0.7, aes(fill=sample_data(physeq_shime)$System)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=palette)
```